# Dynamically (programmatically) created tiles changing its isEnabled property via a timer

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Hey all I am not sure why I am having such a hard time with this but I am needing to be able to change a tiles **isEnabled** property depending on if my program detects an internet connection or not.

The WPF code that I am using and needing to change is the following:

```
<dxlc:TileLayoutControl x:Name="tileLayoutControl1" Margin="150,63,153,57" Padding="5"
   AllowAddFlowBreaksDuringItemMoving="False" AllowItemMoving="False" Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollBars="None"
   TileClick="tileLayoutControl1_TileClick">
</dxlc:TileLayoutControl>
```

This gets populated by the code behind on startup:

```
private void createMenu()
{
   List<String> menuIcons = new List<string>();
        
   menuIcons.Add("gamesIcon.png");
   menuIcons.Add("movieIcon.png");
   menuIcons.Add("musicIcon.png");
   menuIcons.Add("televisionIcon.png");
   menuIcons.Add("youTubeIcon.png");
   menuIcons.Add("androidIcon.png");

   foreach (String item in menuIcons)
   {
       Image finalImage = new Image();
       BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

       image.BeginInit();
       image.UriSource = new Uri("/img/" + item.ToString(), UriKind.Relative);
       image.EndInit();

       finalImage.Source = image;
       image = null;

       tileLayoutControl1.Children.Add(new Tile()
       {
           Content = finalImage,
           Name = item.ToString().Replace(".png", ""),
           Tag = item.ToString().Replace(".png", "").Replace(".jpg", ""),
           Width = 255,
           Height = 288,
           IsEnabled = false,
           Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 50, 20),
           Background = Brushes.Transparent,
           BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)
       }
    }
}
```

and finally the code that I have checking the internet connection within a timer:

```
private bool checkInternet()
{
    try
    {
        Ping myPing = new Ping();
        PingReply reply = myPing.Send("google.com", 1000, new byte[32], new PingOptions());

        return (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public firstWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
    var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
    {
        bool hasInternet = checkInternet();

        TileLayoutControl test = (TileLayoutControl)this.tileLayoutControl1.FindName("youTubeIcon");

        test.IsEnabled = true;
        tileLayoutControl1.RegisterName("youTubeIcon", this.isEnabled = true);
    }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
}
```

I am currently not getting any errors for the lines:

```
TileLayoutControl test = (TileLayoutControl)this.tileLayoutControl1.FindName("youTubeIcon");
test.IsEnabled = true;
tileLayoutControl1.RegisterName("youTubeIcon", this.isEnabled = true);
```

But **test** is **null** and **RegisterName** doesn't seem to change the **isEnabled** property when I try to click on the tile.

I've also read that using **Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"** may be my answer but that seems to only pertain to MVVM type of patterns which I am not using for this particle program.

I also know that checking the **tileLayoutCibtril1** has a **Children** property that does contain my dynamically created icons but **tileLayoutCibtril1.Children** does not have a **.FindName** proeprty.

[image]

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `ApplyTemplate` on `TileLayoutControl` after foreach statement. The template for `TileLayoutControl` has not yet been applied and therefore `FindName` returns `null`. `ApplyTemplate` builds the current template’s visual tree

```
foreach (String item in menuIcons)
{
    ...
}
tileLayoutControl1.ApplyTemplate();
```